# Use of class/struct to store info in R

Tags: r, class

I'm new to R and wanted to ask what is the best object to use when I want to have classes of data (e.g. "Event" class, which contains date, name, etc.).
I don't need any inheritance and no method - only store these fields, and later have a list of these objects. Is class the proper object for me?
Thanks!

Comment: Given the incredibly broad nature of your question, probably a `list` - but you really should cite a *specific* example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, you don't need/want a class in the sense of object oriented programming, as you don't want inheritance or methods.

Since you have heterogenous data types (date, character) you could just use a named list

```
event1 <- list(date=as.POSIXct("2016-01-06"), name="Event 1")
event2 <- list(date=as.POSIXct("2016-01-07"), name="Event 2")
```

store the "objects" in a list again

```
events <- list(event1, event2)
```

and access them like

```
events[[1]]$date   # "2016-01-06 CET"
```

In general, class is just an attribute of an R object which you can set:

```
class(event1) <- "Event"
class(event2) <- "Event"
```